# Select value and display in a combobox if the datetimepicker value lies between two extreme dates in a table in database

Tags: select, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am creating an attendance management system in vb.net and using MS access as my database. I created a leave form in which the student on leave has a roll number and his details along with the from date and to date field.[image: This is the leaves table]

What I'm trying to do is to show all the roll numbers of students in the `ComboBox` on leave if the `DateTimePicker` value is in between the to date and from date, the command that I created as MS access query is selecting the from date and to date ie., extreme dates matching with the `DateTimePicker` value but not showing the values if date is between the to and from date.

[image: This is the attendance form and on leave combobox]

this is the code and query:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    con.Open()

    Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand("Select roll_no From leaves Where semester= " + ComboBox3.SelectedItem + " and (from_date<= #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & "# and to_date >= #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & "#)", con)

    Dim da1 As New OleDbDataAdapter
    da1.SelectCommand = cmd1
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    dt1.Clear()
    da1.Fill(dt1)
    ComboBox4.DataSource = dt1
    ComboBox4.DisplayMember = "roll_no"
    ComboBox4.ValueMember = "roll_no"
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Is there any modification in query through which I can get my desired results to get all the roll no if `DateTimePicker` value is between dates in database?